# How to get selected item in QFileSystemModel and QTreeView

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreeview, qfilesystemmodel

I want to get the file path and the file name from a Tree View in pyqt5. I had it working, but I wanted to implement searching, which works, but doing that I sacrificed the ability to get the filename and file path. 
This is my tree:

```py
class Folder_Screeen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Folder_Screeen, self).__init__(parent)
        self.path = expanduser(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
        self.pathRoot = QDir.rootPath()

        self.labelFileName = QLabel(self)
        self.labelFileName.setText("Search:")
        self.labelFileName.resize(100, 30)

        self.txtSearch = QLineEdit(self)
        self.txtSearch.textChanged.connect(self.on_textChanged)
        self.thumbnail = QLabel(self)

        self.model = QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setRootPath(QDir.rootPath())
        self.model.setFilter(QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QDir.AllEntries | QDir.Dirs | QDir.Files)
        self.proxy_model = QSortFilterProxyModel(recursiveFilteringEnabled = True, filterRole = QFileSystemModel.FileNameRole)
        self.proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.model)
        self.model.setReadOnly(False)
        self.model.setNameFilterDisables(False)

        self.indexRoot = self.model.index(self.model.rootPath())

        self.treeView = QTreeView(self)
        self.treeView.setModel(self.proxy_model)
        self.adjust_root_index()
        # self.treeView.setRootIndex(self.model.index(self.path))
        self.treeView.setRootIndex(self.proxy_model.mapFromSource(self.model.index(self.path)))
        self.treeView.clicked.connect(self.on_treeView_clicked)
        # self.treeView.setSelectionMode(self.SingleSelection)
        self.treeView.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.treeView.setAnimated(True)
        self.treeView.setIndentation(20)
        self.treeView.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.treeView.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.treeView.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.treeView.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
        self.treeView.setEditTriggers(QTreeView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.treeView.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.treeView.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.showContextMenu)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_textChanged(self):
        self.proxy_model.setFilterWildcard("*{}*".format(self.txtSearch.text()))
        self.adjust_root_index() 

    def adjust_root_index(self):
        root_index = self.model.index(self.path)
        proxy_index = self.proxy_model.mapFromSource(root_index)
        self.treeView.setRootIndex(proxy_index)
    def btnAddFolder(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Create Folder", "","All Files (*)", options=options)
        if fileName:
            print(fileName)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Delete:
            if self.lineEditFilePath.text() != '':
                os.remove(self.lineEditFilePath.text())

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QModelIndex)
    def on_treeView_clicked(self, index):
        indexItem = self.model.index(index.row(), 0, index.parent())# print(indexItem)
        fileName = self.model.fileName(indexItem)
        filePath = self.model.filePath(indexItem)

        self.thumbnail.setPixmap(QPixmap(filePath))
        self.thumbnail.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignBottom)

        print(fileName)
        print(filePath)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        m = event.mimeData()
        if m.hasUrls():
            for url in m.urls():
                if url.isLocalFile():
                    event.accept()
                    return
        event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.source():
            QTreeView.dropEvent(self, event)
        else:
            ix = self.indexAt(event.pos())
            if not self.model().isDir(ix):
                ix = ix.parent()
            pathDir = self.model().filePath(ix)
            m = event.mimeData()
            if m.hasUrls():
                urlLocals = [url for url in m.urls() if url.isLocalFile()]
                accepted = False
                for urlLocal in urlLocals:
                    path = urlLocal.toLocalFile()
                    info = QFileInfo(path)
                    n_path = QDir(pathDir).filePath(info.fileName())
                    o_path = info.absoluteFilePath()
                    if n_path == o_path:
                        continue
                    if info.isDir():
                        QDir().rename(o_path, n_path)
                    else:
                        qfile = QFile(o_path)
                        if QFile(n_path).exists():
                            n_path += "(copy)"
                        qfile.rename(n_path)
                    accepted = True
                if accepted:
                    event.acceptProposedAction()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()
    def showContextMenu(self, point):
        ix = self.treeView.indexAt(point)
        if ix.column() == 0:
            menu = QMenu()
            menu.addAction("Rename")
            action = menu.exec_(self.treeView.mapToGlobal(point))
            if action:
                if action.text() == "Rename":
                    self.treeView.edit(ix)
    # TREE VIEW END ====================================
```

I don't get any output of any kind, just a empty string or the main system drive.

The solotuons works if I change this line of code on line 26

```py
self.treeView.setModel(self.proxy_model)
```

to

```py
self.treeView.setModel(self.model)
```

But if I do this, I can't search for files anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set up the QSortFilterProxyModel as a model then the QModelIndex that sends the QTreeView through its signals will belong to that model so obviously they will fail if you want to obtain information from the QFileSystemModel, the solution is to obtain the corresponding QModelIndex using the mapToSource() method:

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QModelIndex)
def on_treeView_clicked(self, index):
    source_index = self.proxy_model.mapToSource(index)
    indexItem = self.model.index(source_index.row(), 0, source_index.parent())
    fileName = self.model.fileName(indexItem)
    filePath = self.model.filePath(indexItem)

    self.thumbnail.setPixmap(QPixmap(filePath))
    self.thumbnail.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignBottom)

    print(fileName)
    print(filePath)
```